# how to put an indent of 0.5in in apa7

Tags: paragraphs

I use the standard apa7 to write my essay but I don't know how to indent each paragraph.
Can somebody help me?
here is the preamble I use for the full document (math document)

```
\documentclass[a4paper,man,floatsintext]{apa7}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsthm,mathtools}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage{graphicx,float}
\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx}
\usepackage{caption,subcaption}
\usepackage{algorithmicx}
\usepackage[ruled]{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=apa]{biblatex}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pdfsync}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\norm}{\lVert}{\rVert}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{77}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{77}
\newtheorem{rem}{Remark}[section]
\newtheorem{defi}{Definition}[section]
\addbibresource{C:/Users/Charriffaini/Documents/latex/distbib.bib}
\fancyhead[l]{}

\begin{document}
The biological clock functions regardless of the normal
24-hour cycle of light and darkness. Light is involved in
resetting and regulating the clock.


The biological clock functions depend on the normal 24-hour cycle of light and darkness regarding its resetting and regulating.
Although the biological clock functions on the normal 24-hour cycle of light and darkness, light is still involved in resetting and regulating the clock.
\end{document}
```

Instead of this small text, I used separated files which I took them in by the following intruction

```
\include{chapter}
```

After the compilation, none of the paragraph is indent.

Comment: It is weird that it is not pre-set in the style sheet? this is mandatory according to the APA manual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add

```
\setlength{\parindent}{0.5in}
```

to your preamble. `\parindent` is the length used to `indent` every `par`agraph.